# Does a carbon frame need two-bolt seat clamp?

Tags: seatpost, carbon, clamp

Does a bike with an [alloy seat post](http://www.giant-bicycles.com/en-gb/gear/product/2015.giant.connect.seatpost/583/62028/) and a [carbon frame](http://www.giant-bicycles.com/en-gb/bikes/model/2013.giant.xtc.composite.2/11895/56865/#overview) need a seat post clamp with two bolts? Most clamps these days seem to be either quick release or single bolt. Is that safe to use with my set up?

I have read a little around the subject and not found any definitive answer.

[image: giant seat clamp and bolt]

Answer (score 4):

On carbon frames I've used, they have had a single bolt clamp like this one, so it should be fine. Personally, I'd like to use a slightly bigger clamp and one of those rubber size-decreasing rings to avoid cracking the frame. If in doubt I'd phone up the manufacturer of the frame and ask!